# How to configure Travis CI to build Node.js without tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, travis-ci

I have a Node.js project as a GitHub repo. There are currently no tests written for the project. My goal is to simply build the project successfully with Travis-CI, without any tests.

I'm currently using the following basic Travis config, `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"

install:
  - npm install
```

The above will fail for me, with the following output:

```
[0Ktravis_fold:end:nvm.install
[0K$ node --version
v9.11.1
$ npm --version
5.6.0
$ nvm --version
0.33.8
travis_fold:start:install
[0Ktravis_time:start:154792e9
[0K$ npm install
[37;40mnpm[0m [0m[30;43mWARN[0m[35m[0m repoName@1.0.0 No repository field.
[0m
up to date in 0.599s

[0Ktravis_fold:end:install
[0Ktravis_time:start:3e0b4d3c
[0K$ npm test

> repoName@1.0.0 test /home/travis/build/githubHandle/repoName.js
> echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

Error: no test specified
[37;40mnpm[0m [0m[31;40mERR![0m[35m[0m Test failed.  See above for more details.
[0m
```

I don't understand why `npm test` is being run. It appears to be failing, as no tests have been written. How could I build/install on Travis *without* checking for tests?

Comment: Because that's the default, per [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/#Default-Build-Script). Also `npm install` is the default install step, so you can remove that. You can skip a step by just giving the value of `true` for it, also per [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Skipping-the-Installation-Step). Read the docs! Alternatively change your `scripts` for `test` in the `package.json` to *not* `exit 1`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the help. I'm sorry, I didn't understand how to disable `npm test` in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`npm test` is [the default build script](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/#Default-Build-Script) for nodejs projects.

If you haven't unit tests or build task, you can skip this step. To do that, add the following line in your travis config file:

```
script: 'true'
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Sorry, I just didn't understand to use `script: 'true'` from the documentation.

Comment: @Madeo, create `.travis.yml` file in the root of your repo, add `script: 'true'` in any place of the file, but without leading spaces.

Comment: but i do want to compile (typescript), but i have no tests... how do i do that?